# In C++, is std::end guaranteed to be O(1) for all container types?

Tags: c++

If a container is likely to contain a large number of items, from a performance perspective, should one write

```
for (auto p = std::begin(container); p != std::end(container); ++p) {...}
```

or should one access the container's end outside the loop

```
const auto& theEnd = std::end(container);
for (auto p = std::begin(container); p != theEnd; ++p) {...}
```

I just wonder if `std::end` is O(1) for containers like sets and lists as well as vectors.

Comment: the optimization probably depends on the compiler, you can also initialize the end element in the initialization part of the for loop

Comment: Note that `C` can count here too, and depending on your loop body, end() might change.

Comment: @MarcoA. Compilers won't be able to change the asymptotic complexity, they only do micro-optimizations.

Comment: @PaulManta: Thats not quite correct. If a compiler can prove your inner loop to always result in the same value, it can reduce `N*N` to `N`, which is however a rare case to happen. Yet alone understanding datastructures...

Comment: @PaulManta I was not referring to that though. I was talking (from a performance perspective) of the comparison in the condition part

Comment: almost certainly, the code generated from these two alternatives will be identical for most compilers and most containers.

Comment: I don't know if `std::end` itself is required to be constant time, but the biggest offender, `std::list::end`, is indeed constant, so I would assume yes.

Comment: `.begin()` and `.end()` have guaranteed constant complexity, see [container.requirements.general]

Comment: @PlasmaHH True. I meant that it won't change the asymptotic complexity unless it is a trivial case.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/83640/420683

Comment: Probably duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9768447/420683

Comment: I'm tempted to -1 for lack of research effort.

Comment: Constant complexity or not, the constant time it adds can be non negligible for simple loops.  And since uses return by value, `auto const&` is likely less effective than simply `auto`.

Comment: There was a talk given by Chandler Carruth where he stated that using `.end()` in the loop conditional is a nightmare for the optimiser (in Clang), so regardless I would hoist it out anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the complexity for `end()` is constant for all containers. The table "Container requirements" in C++ Standard 23.2.1 says so:

> a.end() constant

Answer (score 4):

According to container requirements described in Table 96 of the C++ Standard function `end()` has
constant complexity.