# In what way does end() point to 'one past the end' in non-contiguous containers?

Tags: c++, stl

According to the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183378/in-c-is-stdend-guaranteed-to-be-o1-for-all-container-types) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768447/can-end-be-a-costly-operation-for-stl-containers) question, the C++ standard states in § 23.2.1 that `end()` is of constant time complexity for all stl containers.

If I am understanding correctly:

1. `std::forward_list` only knows about it's first element, and each of the list entries only know about the next element.
2. lists are non-contiguous in memory
3. `a.begin() == a.end()` is true for empty containers `a`
4. `end()` is supposed to be an iterator pointing to 'one past the end of a container'

So while working on some loops over `forward_list`s, I was wondering:

*How can end() be of constant time complexity (i.e. not advance to 'one past the end') in case of forward_list?*

I looked in `forward_list.cpp` and found the declaration

```
iterator       end() _NOEXCEPT
    {return       iterator(nullptr);}
```

That makes sense for the constant time requirement, but not for the - admittedly vage - rule corresponding to point 4 above.

So some questions remain:

- What is 'one past the end' supposed to mean for non-contiguous storage?
- How does `nullptr` fit the definition of 'one past the end'?
- How is `MyForwardList.begin() == MyForwardList.end()` true if `MyForwardList` is empty?
- Why isn't  `end()` always defined as `nullptr`?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong at point 4. Obviously, for node-based containers there can be no concept of "one past the end".

Comment: Basically `end()` can return some sort of sentinel value for the iterator that the class can recognize as signalling something "past the end of the last item in the container".  If a container's iterator were a simple raw pointer, then `end()` might return a null pointer or a pointer with all bits set for example.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I disagree-ish. With any range of iterators, if you iterate to the last element, then increment one more time, you're at the "end" iterator. This is "one past the last element"

Comment: @Mooing   I meant that for contiguous containers there actually is something for past the end iterators to refer to (and there is in C too).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is `one past the end` supposed to mean for non-contiguous storage?

It means whatever you'd get if you incremented an iterator to the last element.

> How does `nullptr` fit the definition of 'one past the end'?

If that's what you get if you increment an iterator to the last element, then it fits the definition.

> How is `MyForwardList.begin() == MyForwardList.end()` true if MyForwardList is empty?

For an empty list, they both return the same thing. Likely an "empty" iterator.

> Why isn't `end()` always defined as `nullptr`?

Because sometimes that's not the most convenient way to define it, and so long as you meet the requirements, you can implement it however you want.

It's basically just a circular definition. The `end` function returns whatever you'd get if you took an iterator to the last element in the list and incremented it or, for an empty list, returns the same thing `begin` returns. So long as all these relationships hold, everything works, regardless of what internal values or logic you use to guarantee the relationships.

Answer (score 5):

"One past the end" is defined in terms of iterator traversal, not memory locations. An `end` iterator is what you get when you take an iterator to the last element and increment it (or `begin` an empty container).

`std::forward_list`'s end iterator pointing at `nullptr` makes sense: in the implementation the last node probably has a `nullptr` next node, and following that link yields indeed the `end` iterator. `std::vector`'s `end` might physically point past the storage for the same reason.

Answer (score 5):

> `end()` is supposed to be an iterator pointing to 'one past the end of a container'.

That's subtly different than what [the standard says](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/container.requirements) (emphasis mine):

> `begin()` returns an iterator referring to the first element in the container. `end()` returns an iterator which is the **past-the-end** value for the container. If the container is empty, then `begin() == end()`;

The standard says "past-the-end", not "one past-the-end".

Implementors are free to chose whatever implementation of "past-the-end" works for a particular container type.

Answer (score 2):

> What is 'one past the end' supposed to mean for non-contiguous storage?

Simply the node that the last valid node points to.

> How does `nullptr` fit the definition of 'one past the end'?

Well, when you build a node based data structure the last valid node will point to `nullptr` for the next node, that is how you know your at the end.

> How is `MyForwardList.begin() == MyForwardList.end()` `true` if `MyForwardList` is empty?

In an empty list the head is `nullptr` or the head points to `nullptr` so comparing `nullptr` to `nullptr` is `true`.

> Why isn't `end()` always defined as nullptr?

Because there is no requirement that your using pointers.