# How do standard library containers know what's before the past-the-end iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, std

I'm trying to implement my own `list` and `map`, and I've been having trouble with the `end()` method since these containers aren't contiguous in memory.

After some research, I've ended up implementing the `end()` as a method that returns an iterator that holds `nullptr`. ([In what way does end() point to 'one past the end' in non-contiguous containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44767368/)). That is enough for most of my implementation, as it verifies that `list::begin() == list::end()` when list is empty (empty list has no nodes so `head` points to `nullptr`).

However, I've seen that it's possible to call `operator--()` on past-the-end iterators to point to the actual last element of the container.

```cpp
int main() {
  {
    std::map<int, char> m = {{1, 'a'}, {2, 'b'}, {3, 'c'}};
    auto it = m.end();
    --it;
    std::cout << it->first << "\n";  // output: 3
    std::cout << it->second << "\n"; // output: c
  }
  {
    std::list<int> l{ 1, 2, 8};
    auto it = l.end();
    --it;
    std::cout << *it << "\n"; // output: 8
  }
}
```

How is this achieved? The implementation of `operator--()` of `_List_iterator` in the gcc changes the current node to point to the previous one:

```cpp
      _Self&
      operator--() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      {
    _M_node = _M_node->_M_prev;
    return *this;
      }
```

But how is this possible if the *node* is out of the list? How does that *node* even exist? Does this mean that an extra node is allocated? Are you actually allowed to call `operator--()` to a past-the-end iterator?

These are the `begin()` and `end()` methods of gcc's `std::list`, in case it helps:

```cpp
     /**
       *  Returns a read-only (constant) iterator that points to the
       *  first element in the %list.  Iteration is done in ordinary
       *  element order.
       */
      _GLIBCXX_NODISCARD
      const_iterator
      begin() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      { return const_iterator(this->_M_impl._M_node._M_next); }

      /**
       *  Returns a read/write iterator that points one past the last
       *  element in the %list.  Iteration is done in ordinary element
       *  order.
       */
      _GLIBCXX_NODISCARD
      iterator
      end() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      { return iterator(&this->_M_impl._M_node); }
```

Comment: nothing prevents the implementation to create an extra node (that has link to the last node as `prev`) and have the iterator point to it. You as a user are not allowed to access that node, just the iterator, but the implementation can.

Comment: This can be done by adding so called [sentinel nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node). But you should also not think of iterators as being pointers they are not (at least not always), they can be objects in their own right so they can have state indicating they are not referring to anything inside the container.

Comment: `struct NodeBase { NodeBase *prev, *next; } sentinel; struct Node : NodeBase { T data; }` may be useful.

Comment: *the end() as a method that returns an iterator that holds `nullptr`.* No, it does not hold `nullptr`. GNU STL `list` returns the `end()` iterator referencing the last list item.

Comment: @273K: no, the GNU `list` returns the `end()` iterator referencing the *sentinel*. (Also, it's not the STL)

Comment: Anyway, GNU list is a cycle  `__first <-> ... <-> __last <-> end() <-> __first` trough `_M_next` and `_M_prev`.

Comment: @MooingDuck There is no *sentinel* in GNU list, `end()`  is referencing `__last._M_node`.

Comment: I've checked and `(--l.begin() == l.end())` returns `true` for `std::list` (gcc 13.1.1) so I guess it's a cycle.

Answer (score 1):

> But how is this possible if the node is out of the list?

Simply, `_M_node->_M_prev` points to the last node.

> How does that node even exist?

In the same way that any node exists. In the case of standard list, it would be created with the provided allocator.

> Does this mean that an extra node is allocated?

That seems like a reasonable conclusion. This pattern is called "sentinel node".

> Are you actually allowed to call operator--() to a past-the-end iterator?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

The standard containers use a bit of a dirty trick (or clever, depending on the way you look at it). (Simplifying the code somewhat).

You start out with an 'base' node type. This is just your forward and backwards pointers.

```cpp
struct ListNodeBase {
  ListNodeBase* next;
  ListNodeBase* prev;
};
```

The list node extends the base node type with the actual data to store. This separation between the pointers and the data is kinda useful!

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct ListNode : public ListNodeBase {
  T data;
};
```

Iteration across the linked list ONLY uses ListNodeBase. To access the data, the objects are upcast to ListNode.

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct ListIter {
   ListNodeBase* current;

   // Here however we upcast to the node type to access the data. 
   T& operator*() const
      { return static_cast< ListNode<T>* >(current)->data; }
   T* operator->() const
      { return &static_cast< ListNode<T>* >(current)->data; }

   // just your bog standard list traversal.. 
   // again, this only operates on the 
   ListIter<T>& operator++() {
      current = current->next;
      return *this;
   }

   ListIter<T>& operator--() {
      current = current->prev;
      return *this;
   }
};
```

The trick though is that there is one node of ListNodeBase *(which is the list container)*, and the rest of the nodes are ListNode.

```cpp
template<typename T> 
struct list : private ListNodeBase {

   typedef ListIter<T> iterator;


   list() 
   {
     // when empty, store pointers to itself 
     this->next = this;
     this->prev = this;
   }

   iterator begin() 
     { return (iterator){ this->next }; }

   iterator end() 
     { return (iterator){ this }; }
};
```

In other words, the list container *is* the sentinel node *(It just doesn't store any data, because it uses the base node type, and node the actual node)*.

Comment: I'd be careful with statements like _"The standard containers use..."_ since there are many standard library implementations around and they are not required to use this technique. It's a very useful answer to OPs question nevertheless.